# div with h1 not accepting css color

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span><a href="profile.html"><img class="propic" src="propic.jpg"/></a></span>
    <span> <h1 id="header"><a href="index.html">B. L. ROSENBERG</a></h1>  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
  /*problem line:*/
    color:white;
    margin-top:-85px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index:-1;
    width:95%;
    background-color:#303030;
    font-size: 36px;
    letter-spacing: 33px;
    font-family: Futura,"Trebuchet MS",Arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    }

 .propic {
z-index:1;
top:20px;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.propic:hover{  
border-style: solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#CC0000;}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use color in `a` tag:

```
#header a{
  color: white;
}
```